# "Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory" when running gufw

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw, websocket

I am trying to run `gufw` to enable traffic through port 443 (for Ogar, not Skype), and gufw logs:

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory
```

`sudo ufw enable` returns:

```
ERROR: Could not load logging rules
```

So I don't think it is a `ufw` error. How should I fix this or how should I allow websocket communication through port 443?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UFW does not "know" what traffic you use a port for, so the only thing you have to do is enable traffic on port 443.

```
sudo ufw allow 443
```

If you want only TCP traffic you can even set

```
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

Comment: So other people can connect to `ws://IP:443` even if ufw errors?

Comment: Actually more context information is needed to figure out why this gufw error message. Did you try this command line version?

Comment: for some reason, logging out and in (restarting with crouton) fixed the problem. Wow.